# Rails: how to use redirect_to properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, path, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following routes defined in my routes file:

```
constraints( subdomain: "abc" ) do
    get "/action" => "abc#init"
    get "/action/:d" => "abc#action"
end
```

I assumed that I can redirect from the `init` action that way:

```
redirect_to action_path(d: "12345")
```

But that way the server infinitely redirects to the `init` action resulting in an browser error.

How can I perform that redircet using tha Rails path helpers?

Comment: what do you mean with init action ?

Comment: @AlexanderLuna just a common public controller action named `init` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name your routes

```
constraints( subdomain: "abc" ) do
  get "/action" => "abc#init", as: :init_action
  get "/action/:d" => "abc#action", as: :d_action # something fancier maybe
end

redirect_to d_action_path(d: 'something')
```